# displaying an image

Tags: image-processing

The specification of a Sony mobile phone is as follows: 
Screen: 5.2 inch, 1080 x 1920 pixels
Camera: 19 MP, 2160p

first, what does the value 2160p represent?

Second: multiplying 1080 x 1920 pixels will give 2,073,600 pixels which is much less than the 19 megapixels of the camera. How the 19 megapixels image be displayed on the 2,073,600 pixels screen? Will the image be downsampled such that the number of its pixels matches the number of pixels on the screen? If so, then what is the benefit of capturing an image with high megapixel value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2160p usually means standard UHD resolution of 3840 x 2160. P means progressive video so it is not interlaced video, but in this case it may just only mean the resolution.

Resolution of camera and display has very little to do with eacy other. Yes, the picture will be downsampled if you want to see the whole photo. But it allows zoom, crop, sending high resolution photos to other people etc, or just in general, a better photo lower resolutions.

Comment: 2160p usually means standard UHD resolution of 3840 x 2160, what does this value represent? why it is included with the 19 MP for camera specification?

Comment: It means resolution of image or video in pixels. It is common resolution as almost all 4K televisions have this resolution, so it is included like many other common resolutions are.